# SCNNode irregular Plane from .dae with Video Texture

Tags: ios, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit, texture-mapping

I have a 3d Plane that is not a SCNPlane. It is a SCNNode that comes from a .dae

That is because the plane is irregular is not a perfect Rectangle.
I want to apply a Video (.mp4) as the texture that matches the geometry of the plane. I was able already to load the video as the texture of a SCNPlane  but that was before I decided to use a custom 3d object.

If I apply the video texture to my new custom geometry.. the video doesnt fit the geometry.

Any ideas what is the right way to do it ? The video loads and shows up.. but is all skewed and doesn't properly match the shape.

```
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: self.theVideoPlayer)
    videoNode.play()
    let skScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 4096, height: 720))
    skScene.addChild(videoNode)
    videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: skScene.size.width/2, y: skScene.size.height/2)
    videoNode.size = skScene.size
    //NodeTree: SKScene -> SKVideoNode

    let baseUrl = "art.scnassets/"
    let sceneUrl = baseUrl + "wallPlane/wallPlane.scn"
    let modelScene = SCNScene(named: sceneUrl)!
    let wallPlaneNode = modelScene.rootNode.childNodes.first! as SCNNode


    wallPlaneNode.geometry!.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = skScene
    wallPlaneNode.geometry!.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

    return wallPlaneNode
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don’t need the complicated SKVideoNode > position it right > SKScene > size it right > assign to material dance to do video in SceneKit. Since iOS 11 you can assign an AVPlayer as a material property’s contents and it’ll automatically map to fill the texture coordinate space. (Don’t be a AVPlayer hater.)

However, you still need to make sure the texture coordinates on your geometry are set up so that one repetition of a texture fills as much of the surface as you want. There are two ways to do that:

1. In whatever software generates the geometry, set up texture mapping (aka UV generation) so that the origin 0,0 is on one corner of the face you want video on and 1,1 is at the other corner.
2. Use `contentsTransform` on your SceneKit material property to stretch or shrink texture coordinate space until your texture fits the way you like. (You can probably do this by trial and error in the Xcode scene editor with a still frame from your video as dummy content.)

Comment: Ohhh.. interesting I think the trick is in the 0,0 1,1 of the exported model. Let me se check that. And thanks for the tip on AVPlayer, im already using an AVPlayer anyway.